# Can someone explain intuitively why union find works to find a cycle in an undirected graph?

Tags: graph-traversal, union-find

I understand how the UF algorithm works to detect a cycle in an undirected graph, but I don't understand why it always works. Could someone explain that intuitively?

Specifically, I don't understand why if you come across an edge that between nodes $u, v$, and if you see that $u$ and $v$ are already in the same disjoint set, it means there is a cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Union find is a data structure (not an algorithm!) that maintains a collection of disjoint sets $\mathcal{S} = \{ S_1, S_2, \dots \}$ under union operations (i.e., replace two sets with their union) and find operations (given an element $x$, report the set $S_i$ containing $x$).

Hopefully it is already clear to you that if, at any point in time, two distinct vertices $u$ and $v$ lie in the same set $S_i \in \mathcal{S}$ then there must be a path $\pi$ from $u$ to $v$ in your input graph $G$.

Suppose then that you are examining a new edge $e=(u,v)$ and you discover that both $u$ and $v$ lie in the same set. We can obtain a cycle $C$ by adding edge $e$ to the path $\pi$. Notice that $C$ lies entirely in $G$, as desired.

Comment: Isn't disjoint set the data structure and union find the algorithm that operates on the disjoint set data structure?

Comment: From what I know union-find and disjoint-set both refer to the data structure. I've never heard of a union-find algorithm.